# Qt busy indicator

Tags: qt, indicator

I want to include a native Qt busy indicator in my app, but I'm not sure how to add it, because it is a part of QML, and I write my app in c++.

http://wiki.qt.io/Busy-Indicator-for-QML

Comment: [Try the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#setOverrideCursor)

Comment: I actually want a graphical indicator instead of changing cursor's appearance. Currently I use a GIF animation for that purpose.

Comment: A very quick google search pointed me here: https://github.com/mojocorp/QProgressIndicator and here: https://github.com/anjinkristou/Qt-busy-indicator. You should give them a try, or study how they did and write your own.

Comment: I am aware of these projects, but my goal is to make my app simpler, and not to add another 300 lines and 5 files. That is why I am interested in Qt's implementation.

Comment: Copy and paste two files (you need just .h and .cpp) with an already working class to your project dir won't make _your_ code more difficult. I'm not aware of a off-the-shelf qt widget to do this. If you find something, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found that QML components can be included with QQuickWidget. That way, QML BusyIndicator is easily added to C++ applications.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html

Comment: Hi, I am interested in your solution. Please can you give some details on how exactly did you implemented it? Thx in advance!

Comment: Just add QQuickWIdget to your .ui, and then you can set it to display busy indicator like this: `ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/BusyIndicator.qml"));`
Also create a `BusyIndicator.qml` according to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-busyindicator.html

Answer (score 5):

Without recurring to third-party implementations or subclassing a widget, the only way I know to display a busy indicator with standard QWidgets is:

```
QProgressBar* bar = new QProgressBar();
bar->setRange(0,0);
```

This will show an "indeterminate" progress bar.

Comment: Sadly I cannot accept this as an answer, because QProgressBar and QML BusyIndicator differ both in appearance and purpose.

Comment: @user3139563 I agree, it's not the same thing. I just fail to see a better approach without recurring to third-party implementations or subclassing a widget. If also [QProgressDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html#details) doesn't fit your needs, I'm officially out of ideas :D